# How can arrows be used for multiple tuples?

Tags: haskell, tuples, generic-programming, arrows

```
foo (a1,a2) (b1,b2) (c1,c2) = (bar a1 b1 c1, bar2 a2 b2 c2)
```

I have a lot of those constructs with different numbers of argument tuples. In the case of

```
foo' (a1,a2) = (bar' a1, bar2' a2)
```

I thought "Hey, that's arrows!":

```
foo' = bar' *** bar2'
```

But I couldn't yet figure out if and how functions with more than one input tuple (as in the first code line) map to arrow style. What is a generic way to handle such functions? Ideally, I always want something like `foo = bar ... bar2`.

Comment: Hmm.. That might be an interesting idea to move `(&&&)`, `(***)` to some class.

Comment: @ony What do you mean? `(&&&)` and `(***)` are already part of a type class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let (****) = uncurry (***) in (bar1, bar2) **** (a1, a2) **** (b1, b2) **** (c1, c2)
```

Comment: Ok, that works, which is good! :D And there's no way to get around explicitly feeding all the tuples into it? I kinda hoped to get something shorter than my standard tuple way.

Comment: You can of course use typeclass hackery to inductively infer the new "tupled" type of the function; I can show you how that's done if Daniel lets me edit his post, or I get to post a new answer.

Comment: @dflemstr: Well if you have a solution which lets me use arrows in this case without specifying the argument tuples, go ahead. :)